# Rest jersey client pass json string to GET method

Tags: json, rest

I want to pass string {"filters":{"keyword":"abc"}} in this format as filter or search parameter to GET method for REST api url.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response2 = null;
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams;
queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("{filters","keyword:abc");
response2 = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8").get(ClientResponse.class);
System.out.println("Response Code = "+response2.getStatus());
outputFilter = response2.getEntity(String.class);
```

The above isn't working for me as filter is getting appended at the end of url
Basically i want to implement the mentioned in REST api+Jersey like the one mentioned below

```
curl -i -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -d '{ "filters": { "keyword":"xyz" } }' ../v1/users?token=[api_token] .
```

Is there another way from where i can pass string as input paramters to GET method and retrieve the associated result
    Please suggest if there is any technique from where i can pass the above mentioned string to GET method and retrieve data as per filter applied

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GET requests should not have a request body/content. Therefore you should not be trying to submit data with your GET. The mentioned CURL command looks like it is incorrectly using the `-d` parameter with a GET.

You need to pass any parameters to GET via the URL.

Also the code looks odd. Do you really mean to put a brace in the key here?

```
queryParams.add("{filters","keyword:abc");
```

I would consult the API docs to see how to provide the filter criteria.

Comment: Sorry,its was a typo for the braces added,basically i want to pass string { "filters": { "keyword":"xyz" } } as input to GET method, ihave tried using MultivaluedMap to pass but its not giving me proper response. Any suggestions

Comment: curl -i -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -d '{ "filters": { "keyword":"xyz" } }' ../v1/users?token=[api_token] when tried from linux box works but not from java code.

Comment: Any suggestions would be helpful